# How can I identify every element in the DOM and the order of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to be able to refer to any element within an HTML DOM and also know what order the elements appear in. I'm hoping elements in the DOM get indexed somewhere from 0 to *<number-of-elements-minus-1>* so that I can identify specific elements and, separately, list those elements in the order they appear within the HTML.

For example, in this HTML, the elements would be numbered from 0 for the **html** element, to 9 for the second **p** element:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Element 2. Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="mainHead">Element 4. How to uniquely identify/order DOM elements</h1>
    <div id="boxedContent">
        <p class="smallText">Element 6. I want to be able to <span class="stress">7. uniquely</span> identify each element and <i>8. also</i> determine the order in which elements appear, reading from top to bottom through the HTML.</p>
    </div>
    <p>Element 9</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a JavaScript/jQuery way of specifying, for example, the **title** element, first **p** element and the **span**. The HTML pages I'll be working with aren't mine, but if there's a whole-DOM element index that I can access I could get to these 3 elements using those index refs - i.e.

- title: 2
- first p: 6
- span: 7

The index numbers would allow me to list the elements in order.

Is this possible? How do I do it?

Comment: `$('selector').index('*')`???  http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: That gives the index relative to the sibling $('selector') elements. I'm looking for an index of all elements, right through the DOM from top to bottom.

Comment: No, it returns index relative to selector passed to `index()` method: `If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

This will create an array-like object of all DOM element.

Then, there are many ways you can get the index of a specific element in that array-like object.

You could do this:

```
var indexOfTitle = elems.indexOf(document.getElementsByTagName('TITLE'));
```

Or, you can create a `for` loop which loops through all the elements in the `elems` variable, and uses a property like `tagName` to find it, etc.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's exactly what I was looking for. As in: 
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');  
alert(elems[9].outerHTML);

Comment: @AlistairChristie I still don't see why you don't want to use jQuery `index()` method. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zw5ga/ EDIT: oops, looks like you want to target element using its index, my bad, off topic jsfiddle. See relevant jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zw5ga/1/  Using as selector: `$('*:eq(9)')`

Comment: That's great. With jQuery $('*:eq(9)') is a very concise way to get what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A better option would be to use `node.compareDocumentPosition(node)` (no jQuery needed)

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition

Given a list of nodes you can sort them this way:

```
nodes.sort((a, b) =>
  a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ? -1 : 1
);
```